How to display decimal points on the x-axis in a forest plot using the forestplot package in R?
I am using the forestplot package in R to create a forest plot, and I am trying to display decimal points on the x-axis tick labels (e.g., 1.0 instead of 1, 2.0 instead of 2). However, despite specifying decimal points in the xticks argument, the plot still rounds these values and only displays integers (1, 2, etc.).
Here is my code:
adjusted_rr <- c(
  NA, 1.00, 0.77, 1.46, 0.79, 0.92, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 0.69, 0.67, 0.94, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 1.21, 0.98, NA,
  NA, 1.17, 1.21, 1.09, 1.23, 1.21, 1.00, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 1.24, 1.22, 1.11, 1.28, 1.24, 0.97, 1.03, NA,
  NA, 1.20, 1.15, 1.00, NA,
  NA, 1.10, 1.14, 1.09, 1.02, 1.00, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 0.86, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 0.88, 0.87, 0.84, 0.97, NA
)

lower_ci <- c(
  NA, 1.00, 0.70, 1.38, 0.72, 0.78, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 0.61, 0.61, 0.88, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 1.15, 0.85, NA,
  NA, 1.09, 1.07, 0.96, 1.07, 1.10, 1.00, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 1.01, 1.12, 0.94, 1.12, 1.13, 0.78, 0.91, NA,
  NA, 1.13, 1.05, 1.00, NA,
  NA, 1.01, 1.06, 1.00, 0.94, 1.00, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 0.78, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 0.81, 0.80, 0.77, 0.90, NA
)

upper_ci <- c(
  NA, 1.00, 0.85, 1.55, 0.87, 1.08, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 0.78, 0.73, 0.99, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 1.29, 1.12, NA,
  NA, 1.27, 1.38, 1.25, 1.41, 1.34, 1.00, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 1.53, 1.34, 1.32, 1.46, 1.35, 1.21, 1.16, NA,
  NA, 1.27, 1.26, 1.00, NA,
  NA, 1.19, 1.24, 1.18, 1.11, 1.00, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 0.95, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 0.95, 0.94, 0.91, 1.04, NA
)

# Forest plot code
forestplot(labeltext = labels,
           mean = adjusted_rr, 
           lower = lower_ci, 
           upper = upper_ci,
           zero = 1.0,  # Center the plot at 1.0
           xlog = FALSE,
           xlab = "Adjusted Rate Ratio",
           boxsize = 0.2,
           is.summary = is.na(adjusted_rr),
           xticks = c(0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0),  # Specify tick marks
           line.margin = 0.4,  # Compress horizontally
           graph.pos = 2, # Adjust vertical spacing
           new_page = TRUE,
           txt_gp = fpTxtGp(label = gpar(cex = 0.8), 
                            ticks = gpar(cex = 0.8), 
                            xlab = gpar(cex = 1)),
           grid = TRUE)

I’ve also tried manually modifying the axis using axis() and sprintf() to enforce the decimal points, but nothing seems to work. The x-axis still displays as 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, instead of the desired 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0.
How can I enforce the x-axis to display decimal points in the tick labels for my forest plot? Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!

There is a comment in the documentation that provides a solution (https://github.com/cran/forestplot/blob/21c3d27d522fff669fa5e3852b7e71decf358741/R/forestplot.R#L108; essentially, 'add a label attribute to the xticks vector'):
library(forestplot)
#> Loading required package: grid
#> Loading required package: checkmate
#> Loading required package: abind
adjusted_rr <- c(
  NA, 1.00, 0.77, 1.46, 0.79, 0.92, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 0.69, 0.67, 0.94, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 1.21, 0.98, NA,
  NA, 1.17, 1.21, 1.09, 1.23, 1.21, 1.00, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 1.24, 1.22, 1.11, 1.28, 1.24, 0.97, 1.03, NA,
  NA, 1.20, 1.15, 1.00, NA,
  NA, 1.10, 1.14, 1.09, 1.02, 1.00, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 0.86, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 0.88, 0.87, 0.84, 0.97, NA
)

lower_ci <- c(
  NA, 1.00, 0.70, 1.38, 0.72, 0.78, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 0.61, 0.61, 0.88, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 1.15, 0.85, NA,
  NA, 1.09, 1.07, 0.96, 1.07, 1.10, 1.00, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 1.01, 1.12, 0.94, 1.12, 1.13, 0.78, 0.91, NA,
  NA, 1.13, 1.05, 1.00, NA,
  NA, 1.01, 1.06, 1.00, 0.94, 1.00, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 0.78, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 0.81, 0.80, 0.77, 0.90, NA
)

upper_ci <- c(
  NA, 1.00, 0.85, 1.55, 0.87, 1.08, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 0.78, 0.73, 0.99, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 1.29, 1.12, NA,
  NA, 1.27, 1.38, 1.25, 1.41, 1.34, 1.00, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 1.53, 1.34, 1.32, 1.46, 1.35, 1.21, 1.16, NA,
  NA, 1.27, 1.26, 1.00, NA,
  NA, 1.19, 1.24, 1.18, 1.11, 1.00, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 0.95, NA,
  NA, 1.00, 0.95, 0.94, 0.91, 1.04, NA
)

labels <- rep("label_tmp", 59)

# Forest plot code
forestplot(labeltext = labels,
           mean = adjusted_rr, 
           lower = lower_ci, 
           upper = upper_ci,
           zero = 1.0,  # Center the plot at 1.0
           xlog = FALSE,
           xlab = "Adjusted Rate Ratio",
           boxsize = 0.2,
           is.summary = is.na(adjusted_rr),
           xticks = c(0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0),  # Specify tick marks
           line.margin = 0.4,  # Compress horizontally
           graph.pos = 2, # Adjust vertical spacing
           new_page = TRUE,
           txt_gp = fpTxtGp(label = gpar(cex = 0.8), 
                            ticks = gpar(cex = 0.8), 
                            xlab = gpar(cex = 1)),
           grid = TRUE)


# add a label attribute to the xticks vector:
my_ticks <- c(0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0)
attr(my_ticks, "labels") <- c("0.5", "1.0", "1.5", "2.0")

# Forest plot code
forestplot(labeltext = labels,
           mean = adjusted_rr, 
           lower = lower_ci, 
           upper = upper_ci,
           zero = 1.0,  # Center the plot at 1.0
           xlog = FALSE,
           xlab = "Adjusted Rate Ratio",
           boxsize = 0.2,
           is.summary = is.na(adjusted_rr),
           xticks = my_ticks,  # Specify tick marks
           line.margin = 0.4,  # Compress horizontally
           graph.pos = 2, # Adjust vertical spacing
           new_page = TRUE,
           txt_gp = fpTxtGp(label = gpar(cex = 0.8), 
                            ticks = gpar(cex = 0.8), 
                            xlab = gpar(cex = 1)),
           grid = TRUE)


Created on 2024-11-28 with reprex v2.1.0
